# Parsing XML with namespace in google apps script

Tags: xml, google-apps-script

I'm trying to parse XML from SportsRadar api and retrieve info about medals per country for the Olympics. The API seems to be using namespaces and I can't quite figure out how to parse the XML.

If I look at the top of the XML it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<medals xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.sportradar.com/sportsapi/v1/winterolympics" generated_at="2017-12-03T12:23:38+01:00" xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.sportradar.com/sportsapi/v1/winterolympics http://schemas.sportradar.com/bsa/winterolympics/v1/xml/endpoints/winterolympics/medals.xsd">
  <medals_by_country>
    <medal_info country="Slovenia" country_code="SLO" ioc_code="SLO" total_ranking="1" gold_ranking="1" total="24" gold="14" silver="3" bronze="7"/>
    <medal_info country="Canada" country_code="CAN" ioc_code="CAN" total_ranking="2" gold_ranking="1" total="17" gold="9" silver="5" bronze="3"/>
    <medal_info country="Germany" country_code="GER" ioc_code="GER" total_ranking="3" gold_ranking="1" total="19" gold="8" silver="6" bronze="5"/>
```

And if I get the root element and look at the children, I use this code:

```
var xml_root = xmlData.getRootElement()
Logger.log( xml_root.getChildren() )
```

and get this output:

```
[18-02-10 15:29:52:056 EST] [[Element: <medals_by_country [Namespace: http://schemas.sportradar.com/sportsapi/v1/winterolympics]/>], [Element: <medals_by_sport [Namespace: http://schemas.sportradar.com/sportsapi/v1/winterolympics]/>]]
```

So looking at the docs it seems like `getChildText(name, namespace)` should be my magic ticket to get the medals by country info. So I try:

`var tst = xml_root.getChildText('medals_by_country', 'http://schemas.sportradar.com/sportsapi/v1/winterolympics');`

but I get an error telling me "Cannot find method getChildText(string,string)". I'm parsing that to mean that the namespace should not be passed as a string, maybe? But I can't figure out what it should be passed as.

I tried just grabbing the first country info by doing:

```
xml_root.getChild('medals_by_country').getChildren('medal_info');
```

And `xml_root.getChild('medals_by_country')` returns null. I presume this is because I'm not referencing it by namespace...

So what should I be doing in order to get the medal info for each country? It feels like I'm close but there's something I'm not groking here.

EDIT:
I figured out how to create a namespace (I think). I did the following

```
var ns = XmlService.getNamespace("xsi", "http://schemas.sportradar.com/sportsapi/v1/winterolympics");
```

Buuut... I'm still pulling nulls from the xml, much to my chagrin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this sample script? In this script, your xml data was tested as a sample data. For this, I added `</medals_by_country></medals>` at the end of xml. Values of `medal_info` can be retrieved by `getAttributes()`.

#### Sample script :

```
function myFunction(){
  var xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><medals xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.sportradar.com/sportsapi/v1/winterolympics" generated_at="2017-12-03T12:23:38+01:00" xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.sportradar.com/sportsapi/v1/winterolympics http://schemas.sportradar.com/bsa/winterolympics/v1/xml/endpoints/winterolympics/medals.xsd"><medals_by_country><medal_info country="Slovenia" country_code="SLO" ioc_code="SLO" total_ranking="1" gold_ranking="1" total="24" gold="14" silver="3" bronze="7"/><medal_info country="Canada" country_code="CAN" ioc_code="CAN" total_ranking="2" gold_ranking="1" total="17" gold="9" silver="5" bronze="3"/><medal_info country="Germany" country_code="GER" ioc_code="GER" total_ranking="3" gold_ranking="1" total="19" gold="8" silver="6" bronze="5"/></medals_by_country></medals>';
  var xmlData = XmlService.parse(xml);
  var xml_root = xmlData.getRootElement();
  var res = [];
  var c1 = xml_root.getChildren();
  for (var i in c1) {
    var c2 = c1[i].getChildren();
    for (var j in c2) {
      var c3 = c2[j].getAttributes();
      var temp = {};
      for (var k in c3) {
        temp[c3[k].getName()] = c3[k].getValue();
      }
      res.push(temp);
    }
  }
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(res))
}
```

#### Result :

```
[
    {
        "country": "Slovenia",
        "country_code": "SLO",
        "ioc_code": "SLO",
        "total_ranking": "1",
        "gold_ranking": "1",
        "total": "24",
        "gold": "14",
        "silver": "3",
        "bronze": "7"
    },
    {
        "country": "Canada",
        "country_code": "CAN",
        "ioc_code": "CAN",
        "total_ranking": "2",
        "gold_ranking": "1",
        "total": "17",
        "gold": "9",
        "silver": "5",
        "bronze": "3"
    },
    {
        "country": "Germany",
        "country_code": "GER",
        "ioc_code": "GER",
        "total_ranking": "3",
        "gold_ranking": "1",
        "total": "19",
        "gold": "8",
        "silver": "6",
        "bronze": "5"
    }
]
```

#### Reference :

- [getAttributes()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/element#getAttributes())

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: not only did you completely understand my question, you made it work with my somewhat limited example XML. Thank you, I really appreciate it. This is my first js experiment and you really helped me understand the process. Thank you.